# Cannot open include file error while building with scons

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, scons

I downloaded mitsuba_shapenet renderer on github few days ago, and I tried to compile the source code with scons. But there are some problems.
At first I got the message: ‘cl’ is not recognized as an internal or external command. Then I set the environment variables and the error message changed:

```
file F:\DataSets\MERL 100 Material Library\examples\mitsuba_shapenet\mitsuba_shapenet\build\SConscript.configure,line 137:
Configure(confdir = .sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for cl ...
.sconf_temp\conftest_0.cpp <-
  |#include <sstream>
  | int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  | std::ostringstream oss;
  | return 0;
  | }
cl /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_0.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_0.cpp /nologo /Oi /Ot /Oy /Ob1 /Gs /GF /Gy /fp:fast /D WIN32 /D WIN64 /W3 /EHsc /GS- /GL /MD /D MTS_DEBUG /D SINGLE_PRECISION /D SPECTRUM_SAMPLES=3 /D MTS_SSE /D MTS_HAS_COHERENT_RT /D _CONSOLE /D NDEBUG /D OPENEXR_DLL /openmp /nologo /D GLEW_MX /Idependencies\include\openexr /Idependencies\include\openexr /Iinclude /Idependencies\include
conftest_0.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: “corecrt.h”: No such file or directory
scons: Configure: no
```

Then I searched corecrt.h in my computer and found it here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt
```

Then I tried to add the path to include and libs in Visual Studio 2017, but it still didn't work. And I'm using Windows 10 64 bits.

I'm worrying about this problem, how to build this source code successfully?

Comment: If you open a "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" (which should have all paths and environment variables correct to begin with) and run from there, do you still have the same problems?

Comment: What version of SCons are you running?  You need at least SCons 3.0.0 as VS2017 support was added in 3.0.0, But I'd suggest 3.0.1 as it resolved some py2/py3 issues.  (See: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SConsProject/scons/rel_3.0.0/src/CHANGES.txt)